# how to add a welcome activity to allow user to choose his language and change language of all activitys

Tags: java, android, local, startup

I'm trying to build a very simple application with many `activities`.

In this app I have a `WelcomeActivity` for user to choose his `language` with two buttons, one for `English` and one for `Arabic` then i want after user choose his language , the language will be changing at all activities and this `WelcomeActivity` will be run only for the first time and never show again.

**any help ?**

Comment: How do u provide language content , is it through localized xml file stored in resource folder?

Comment: yes i have two strings folders one for english and one for arabic

Comment: I guess it makes more sense to rely on the system features where a user can change the language globally for all apps. Nothing to do on your side then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar”,"XX");

 private void updateLocale(locale) {
    final Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale.setDefault(baseLocal);
    configuration.locale = baseLocal;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

How to restore the selected language in next launch.? [ Better to store it in a shared preference.] I hope you might be knowing how to store. You just need to store "ar" or "en" text in preference.  On next launch you have to read back and form Locale and pass updateLocale() method.

You can make use OnConfigurationChanged Method

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
        Locale.setDefault(mCurrentLocale);
        configuration.locale = mCurrentLocale;..locale from preference or latest selected.
        getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());      
    }
```

Where mCurrentLocale can be read from shared preference which u stored earlier.

How to store language in shared preference in this case

```
   final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    this);
sharedPreferences().putString(KEY_STORE_CURRENT_LOCALE, language_code).commit();
```

How to get language from shared preference in this case

```
        final String current = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_STORE_CURRENT_LOCALE,
               language_code_english);
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: thanks, just need more details about how to use sahred preference in this case

Comment: updated my answer with how to use shared preference. you have to read a little bit about. It answers help you please accept the answer and Upvote. So It will help other! @YASSBRATop10

Comment: ok thank's men ,are this can make change language of all activities ?@lib4

Comment: Locale.setDefault(mCurrentLocale); should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the language value in shared preferences. In my case i have en and np as english and nepali language. First i took and stored the value in shared preference as language, then i have a lang button. In my case I have restarted my app because my user needs to load data again from another api. Then i have appended the shared preference string to API.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
            String language = preferences.getString("language","en");

            lang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(language.equals("en")){
                        Util.setLanguage("np");
                        Intent restartIntent = new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this,SplashActivity.class);
                        restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(restartIntent);
                        (NavDrawerActivity.this).finish();
                    }else {
                        Util.setLanguage("en");
                        Intent restartIntent = new Intent(NavDrawerActivity.this,SplashActivity.class);
                        restartIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(restartIntent);
                        (NavDrawerActivity.this).finish();
                    }
                }
            });
```